# Allow inner elements of label to trigger label action when touched on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, label

I have labels with the markup:

```
<label for="fieldname" class="question__checkboxBlock-label">
    <i class="question__checkboxBlock-label-icon"></i>
    <span class="question__checkboxBlock-label-tex">Some question text</span>
</label>
```

These work fine on desktop, but on mobile only the outer edge of the label actually triggers the label action of checking the related checkbox. Is there anything I can do with CSS as opposed to Javascript that will make the whole label clickable?

Comment: Try adding label > * { pointer-events:none; }

Comment: @SahilDhir Lovely, worked a treat thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :)